# Generating html option tags by array_push in codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I use codeigniter and I have a form which is using this structure for `option` tag:

```
$options = array(
              'small'  => 'Small Shirt',
              'med'    => 'Medium Shirt',
              'large'   => 'Large Shirt',
              'xlarge' => 'Extra Large Shirt',
            );

echo form_dropdown('shirts', $options, 'large');
```

Would produce:

```
<select name="shirts">
<option value="small">Small Shirt</option>
<option value="med">Medium Shirt</option>
<option value="large" selected="selected">Large Shirt</option>
<option value="xlarge">Extra Large Shirt</option>
</select>
```

But I want to retrieve data from database. And I use this:

```
$options = array();
foreach(...) {
  array_push($options, $menu_name_db[$i]);
}
```

Would produce:

```
<select name="shirts">
<option value="0">Small Shirt</option>
<option value="1">Medium Shirt</option>
<option value="2" selected="selected">Large Shirt</option>
<option value="3">Extra Large Shirt</option>
</select>
```

But I want to initialize the value from database, for example by their id or cost.

How can I do that?

Comment: So `$menu_name_db[$i]` contains the description like 'Small Shirt'. What entry contains the value like 'small'?

Comment: @Barry this is exactly my question :)

Comment: print_r($menu_name_db); i need to know what $menu_name_db contains..

Comment: But how do you populate $menu_name_db?

Comment: is $menu_name_db from db. then give me a sample structure of that array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is when building your table :

```
$options = array();
$menu_name_db = $this->db->get('yourtablemenu')->result();

foreach($menu_name_db as $m) 
{
  $options[$m->id] = $m->title; 
}

echo form_dropdown('shirts', $options, 'large');
```

The key of your array will then id of your table.